# AWS Elasticache redis cluster configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache

I'm a bit new to terraform and was and needed some help on what's the issue with this. It creates the according resources but when connecting to the endpoint, I get a timeout. I noticed the security group isn't actually being created but I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

configuration:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "example" {
  cluster_id           = "cluster-example"
  engine               = "redis"
  node_type            = "cache.m4.large"
  num_cache_nodes      = 1
  parameter_group_name = "default.redis3.2"
  engine_version       = "3.2.10"
  port                 = 6379
}

resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "Used by the example Redis cluster"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"

  ingress {
    description      = "TLS from VPC"
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = [aws_vpc.example.cidr_block]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc" "example" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "example"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.example.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/20"

  tags = {
    Name = "example"
  }
}

resource "aws_elasticache_subnet_group" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "Example subnet group"
  subnet_ids  = ["${aws_subnet.example.id}"]
}
```

connection to endpoint:

```
import os
import redis

ENDPOINT = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST')

client = redis.Redis(host=ENDPOINT, port=6379, db=0)

client.ping()
```

(passwordless cluster)

EDIT:
I call the endpoint in python on my local machine.

Comment: You are connecting from where? Lambda, ec2, home/work network?

Comment: I call the endpoint using python on my home network, locally

Answer (score 1):

You can't access EC cluster from outside of AWS directly, as it can [only be accessed from VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/accessing-elasticache.html). You must use VPN, Direct Connect or SSH tunnel if you want to connect from your home network.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it so that I can connect locally with a security group?

EDIT: Looks like a VPN is the way to go, I'll give this an attempt. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @apinanyogaratnam SSH tunnel is the easiest to setup for testing and development.